Meta Spark can't detect linked accounts
It seems that Meta Spark can't detect the linked instagram and facebook accounts to the Meta account, although they are.

And just a minute ago, that yellow message didn't even appear. I was able to press "Send" but then it would just load forever or sometimes show this:

Can't send on iph either, I get this error:

But someone else, with the same folder project, is able to send the filter to instagram without any issue.
Any ideas?
I tried to disconnect from all accounts, logged out from Meta Spark Studio, reinstalled, and cleared the browser history, still nothing.
